# What are the implications of rating movies strategically?

Tags: probability

**Context and Intuition**

Consider a website which allows users to rate movies out of ten. The ratings are assumed to be $\in \{1,2, \dots ,10\}$. The website displays an aggregate rating which is the mean of the individual ratings. Needless to say, if the website is popular, the aggregate score means quite a lot, as it is a pretty decent measure of the movie's reception. Note that this example is based on actual sites (for instance, IMDb, although the specific algorithm IMDb uses is more complicated than what I describe).

When a user votes on a movie, he may be inclined to vote *strategically*. For instance, let's say the user genuinely believes that a given movie is an $8$, but the current aggregate rating is $6.4$, so the user "strategically" gives the movie a $10$ in an effort to raise the aggregate rating to the rating the user thinks the movie deserves. More precisely, if the current aggregate rating is $r \in [1,10]$, a strategic voter would rate $10$ if his genuine rating is $>r$ and $1$ if his genuine rating is $<r$. The strategic voter would only rate honestly if the aggregate vote is precisely the same as his genuine rating, or if his vote is the very first vote.

In practice, we would expect some voters to be honest (that is to say, the rating they give is the rating they believe the movie deserves), and some voters to be strategic, as described above.

The question that arises is, simply, does the presence of strategic voters skew the aggregate rating at all, at least as the number of individual ratings tends to infinity? If the end goal of the website is an accurate aggregate rating for the movie, corresponding closely to the mean of individuals' genuine ratings, would it be in the website's interest to actively discourage strategic voting? Or is allowing it acceptable, and the presence of strategic voters makes no difference?

**Formal Statement of the Problem**

More precisely, let $R_1, R_2, R_3, \dots$ be an infinite i.i.d sequence taking values in $\{1, 2, \dots, 10\}$. Put $\overline{R_n} = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{1 \leq i \leq n} R_i$ and $\mu = \mathbb{E}(R_i)$. By the strong law of large numbers, $\overline{R_n} \xrightarrow{\text{a.s.}} \mu$. Now let $X_1, X_2, \dots$ be an i.i.d sequence taking values in $\{\text{honest, strategic}\}$. Consider the following sequence of random variables $Q_1, Q_2, \dots$ defined recursively so that $$Q_i =
\begin{cases}
R_i  & \text{if} \ X_i = \text{honest} \\
R_i &  \text{if} \ X_i = \text{strategic and} \  i=1 \\
R_i & \text{if} \ X_i = \text{strategic}, \  i>1  \ \text{and} \ \frac{1}{i-1}\sum_{k=1}^{i-1} Q_k = R_{i} \\
10 &  \text{if} \ X_i = \text{strategic}, \  i>1  \ \text{and} \ \frac{1}{i-1}\sum_{k=1}^{i-1} Q_k < R_{i} \\
1 &  \text{if} \ X_i = \text{strategic}, \  i>1  \ \text{and} \ \frac{1}{i-1}\sum_{k=1}^{i-1} Q_k > R_{i}
\end{cases}$$

Putting $\overline{Q_n} = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{n} Q_k$, must it be the case that $\overline{Q_n} \xrightarrow{\text{a.s.}} \mu$?

Comment: Consider the case when everyone is strategic. Then the rating tends to the value $Q$ satisfying $Q=10\operatorname{Pr}[R_i>Q]$, which I guess doesn't equal $\mu$ in general.

Comment: For example, suppose half the users have $R_i=10$ and half have $R_i=4$. Then $\mu=7$ but $\bar Q_n\to 5$.

Comment: @Rahul Yes, that works. Thanks!

Comment: Erratum: I assumed that scores lie in $\{0,\dots,10\}$ instead of $\{1,\dots,10\}$.